# Parallax banner not working with nav bar

Tags: html, css

I have run into a problem and was wondering if anyone could help. I am trying to create a website for a uni project but can't seem to make the navbar show up above the banner element. This error only occurred after I added some 'Parallax' css for the banner. 
This is a link to my website (hard to explain)
http://itsuite.it.brighton.ac.uk/ar707/mysite/

I have attached  the css and html below (I have created a separate style sheet so there is no style tag included)

---

```
<div id="navcontainer">
  <ul id="navlist">
    <li><a id="logo" href="index.html"> </a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="guide.html">My Guide</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <!--The 'wrapper' div contains all the page content and can be styled -->
  <a id="top"></a>
  <!--anchoring the link from the bottom so that i can come to the top of the page-->

<header id="banner">
<!--The main heading for the page -->
    <h1>Anish's Learning Journal</h1>
    <!-- <img alt="Feel free to use these photos and videos in your work" src="images/dsc_0116.jpg"  > -->

</header>
```

Comment: sorry for the format, not sure why it din't upload properly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, read [edit-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to write a readable question. I've edited your question, you should only add the css code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give your nav a z-index greater than the z-index of your banner (which is 0 by default), try

```
#navcontainer {
background-color: #323232;
height: 43px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
opacity: .95;
z-index: 1;
```

}